# Empty lines or not?

Tags: sectioning

I have used LaTeX for a while, but something has been bugging me:

- When should one use empty lines with LaTeX inside the document environment, besides when one wants a text indentation?
- Should I use empty lines before or after a `\part`,`\chapter`,`\section` etc.?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use blank lines where logically you want a paragraph break. Section headings naturally form paragraph breaks already so a blank line before or after them makes no difference. For other constructs such as lists leave a blank line around them if they are not considered part of a surrounding paragraph and do not leave blank line if the list is part of the surrounding paragraph.

Note that whether paragraphs are indented or not is a style choice which should be more or less independent of the markup around individual paragraphs.

Answer (score 10):

- In text mode, use (one or more) empty lines between paragraphs.
- Do *not* use empty lines immediately ahead of display-math environments, i.e., do not start a paragraph with a display-math environment.
- Do *not* use empty lines in displayed equation environments. (If you load the `amsmath` package, having empty lines inside `equation`, `align`, etc. will throw an error.)
- Floating environments such as `figure` and `table` can -- *but do not have to be* -- surrounded by blank lines. Providing whitespace around these environments, i.e., placing them between text paragraphs, almost certainly makes your code easier to read.
- Using empty lines immediately before or after `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, etc. is neither required nor prohibited. It's probably a good idea, though, to use whitespace generously to improve the legibility of one's code.

Comment: actually figure and table don't insert paragraph breaks (on the outside) the content of course starts and ends in vertical mode, but if you go `hello\begin{figure}...\end[figure}world` it will typeset as `helloworld` with no paragraph break (or space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Good point! I will edit my posting...

Comment: Does inserting a blank line right before, or right after a `\section` change the output?

Comment: @ebo -- If a document class that uses the `\@startsection` mechanism is in use, inserting blank lines immediately before or after a `\section`-type instruction does not affect the output. For sure, all of the "standard" LaTeX document classes make use of the `\@startsection` mechanism to organize `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. The `\chapter` and `\part` instructions, which use a different mechanism internally, are also unaffected by the presence of absence of surrounding whitespace.